# Modifying data being used in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

Okay, so my issue is that I have to catch delete and rename events (which) I can do. And modify the data in threads to handle this so that the deleted files are removed and the renamed files have their data changed. This is psuedo-code for the system, just to get an idea of what it looks like. Whenever I delete, the system throws an exception, however it is not caught, so I have been having a hard time figuring out how to go about solving or rewriting the solution. The other portion of this is that I will have multiple managers running at once, but I figure if I can't get one to work... then this is futile.

```
Main
{
    public void Run()
    {
        List<FileInfo> someData = new List<FileInfo>();
        FileWatcher fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(@"C:\USers\user1\Documents");

        fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilter.Last
        fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDelete);
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Manager aManager = new Manager(someData);
        Thread aThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(aManager.ExecuteTask));
        aThread.Start();
    }

    static void OnDelete(object sender, Event e)
    {
        aManager.Pause();
        aManager.RemoveData(e.FileInfo);
        aManager.Resume();
    }
}


Manager
{
    ExecuteTask()
    {
        while(someData.Count > 0)
        {
            while (paused) ; // <- This is something I am trying to add
            PreformSubTask(someData[0]);
        }
    }

    PreformSubTask()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            Worker someWorker = new Worker(someData[0]);
            Thread someThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(worker.ExecuteTask()));
        }

        worker.Join(someSetOfTime);

        lock(_locker)
        {
            someData.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    Pause()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (!paused) paused = true;
        }
    }

    Resume
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (paused) paused = false;
        }
    }

    RemoveData(FileInfo toRemove)
    {
        someData.RemoveAll(sd => sd.Equals(someData));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use tags in the title of your question.

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event Viewer? Did it have a chace to record any fault?

Comment: Thanks for the correction of the title Bryan. Yes, I am using the event viewer, that is where I write out all of my debug (I am writing a service). I will add more debug so that I can more precisely find when the error is occurring.

Comment: The "system crashes"?  I assume you mean that your application throws an exception?  Can you edit your post and show the first couple relevant lines from the exception?

Comment: To be honest, it's not very clear to me what you're trying to do. Could you please elaborate? What kind of errors are you getting?
It seems to me that someData is a List, and I think that instead of pausing and resuming the manager, you can declare RemoveData as a synchronized method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use *thread synchronization* to protect data shared between multiple threads from being corrupted.  See the `lock` keyword or the `Mutex` class.

But, I'd really recommend not re-writing task queueing/scheduling and use something off-the-shelf.

What is wrong with simply doing the processing in the OnDelete handler?

Comment: the issue is that I cannot lock the data, the data is files that the user is modifying, and I need to be able to manipulate that list... more freely as to allow for the files to be removed and added to the managers rapidly.

Comment: You realize if you can't lock the data, you're screwed?  You can't expect two threads to be modifying the same data freely to *not* corrupt data.

Comment: Locking data doesn't mean the data can't be modified by other threads, just that it can't be modified at certain times.  I'd suggest packaging up the data that won't be shared.  E.g. create another data structure and push it on to a stack and allow only one thread at a time to pop data off that stack.

Comment: Well, the data is files. So, what I do is queue the files to be uploaded or downloaded, but I have to be able to handle the event in which they are deleted or renamed. So, I should be able to remove or change them while they are queued, not while they are working (I obtain a file lock so that the file can be opened and edited while being transferred, but not renamed or deleted).

Comment: I'm said the lock keyword, not a lock on the file.

Comment: Okay. I see what you mean, I will try locking the list itself (is that correct?).

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure that each thread in your application (whether you create it or not) modifies data independently of other threads.  This can be done with the lock keyword.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14534/discussion-between-blaze-phoenix-and-peter-ritchie)